# how to scraping multiple image tag under div tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

i want to scraping multiple image under `div` tag but getting error

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

html example

```
<div class="class_name">
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
<img src="#">
</div>
```

python 3

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'web_url'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

div = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "class_name"})
img = div.find_all('img')

for image in img:
    print(image['src'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to extract all image's `src=...`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="class_name">
<img src="#1">
<img src="#2">
<img src="#3">
<img src="#4">
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for d in soup.select('div.class_name'):
    for i in d.select('img'):
        print(i['src'])
```

Prints:

```
#1
#2
#3
#4
```

Comment: thank you, this working, and can you explain to me why i got error in first place

Comment: @andruwoei In your code `div` is of type `ResultSet`. This type doesn't have `.find_all()` method, so `img = div.find_all('img')` will throw an error.